# Lookup Values Based on Values in Other Cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

I have an inventory list that contains a manufacturer name and product category for each product.  I want to look up the code for the manufacturer and the category code for the product and place the two codes, comma delimited, in a cell.

For example:

if `ProductManufacturer = "manufacturer1"`, the lookup result for "manufacturer1" might be a code of "42".

If `ProductCategory = "Miscellaneous Part"`, the lookup result for "Miscellaneous Part" might be "50".

So the computed cell would contain: `42,50`

The spreadsheet might look like this:

```
         Col A            Col B           Col C             Col G     Col H          Col I      Col J
   1  ProductMfr      ProdCategory        Codes         Lookup Tables:
   2  manufacturer1   Miscellaneous Part  42,50         Manufacturer  MfrCode     ProdCategory  CatCode
   3                                                    Manufacturer1   42        refrigerator       21
   4                                                    Manufacturer2  103        bbq grill          92
   5                                                    Manufacturer3   94        dishwasher         45
   6                                                    Manufacturer4   75        oven               73    
   7                                                     .  .  .  .               burners            18
   8                                                                              Miscellaneous Part 50
   9                                                                                .  .  .  .
```

What kind of formula would I use to produce the comma delimited codes in column C?

Comment: So the problem is needing to lookup the category IDs in the correct list for the manufacturer?  Can you provide a general description for how the data is structured?  For example, how do you know which list goes with which manufacturer?  Are the categories the same but the category IDs vary by Manufacturer or does each manufacturer have a unique set of categories?

Comment: The categoryid is randomized by my ecommerce platform, so each manufacturer is given a  seemingly random 2-3 digit category id. In order to upload this category into the website instead of manually adjusting this for every product of my inventory a cell titled categoryid including the categoryid,and (sub)categoryid seperated by commas. So based on what my manufacturer cell equals and what category type the item is it should return a value seperated by commas. Like in my example 42,50 would translate on the website to Ex. Sony>Televisions.

Comment: The data from 2 cells in two different columns has to be able to change what the data in the third column is, the categoryid numbers have to be input into the formula by me seeing as they are seemingly random.

Comment: I understand conceptually what you want to accomplish but a solution needs to reflect dealing with the data.  I'm sort of lost as to what the data looks like and how the codes are specified--the mechanics of looking at and interpreting the data so that a solution can be applied.  It would be a tremendous help for anyone with a potential solution for you if you could put some sample data into the question along with a brief description of how to use it.  Step through a short example of how you would manually accomplish the result (the logic, not how you would code it in Excel).

Comment: It won't let me add a picture so I'll try and be more specific. I have a table 2 by 8, that contains a column of manufacturer names and a column of categoryid for those. So it looks like, Brand1 = 43, Brand2 = 42, Brand3 = 193, Brand4 = 188, etc.; I have the same table style for the category type, item1 = 196,etc. On my current inventory list I have a column named category type which would display one of 9 categories per product, the same goes for the manufacturer column with 8 different manufacturers. The manufacturers and columns match the aforementioned table.

Comment: I need a formula to make a new column display the ID#s seperated by commas for each manufacturer and category type id that applies. Hence my previous example.

Comment: Can you just type some columns of information into the question?  It doesn't need to be the whole database, just a few entries for each table.  Then explain an example for data taken from what you enter.  There are manufacturers, categories, category IDs, sub-category IDs, category types, products, etc.  Without seeing exactly what you're talking about, it is very confusing.  What relates the values?  What does the data you get look like?  How do you know how to get from that to a series of numbers you want to enter in a cell?

Comment: added a mock list of manufacturers and category types with their corresponding id's, I dont know what else you would want as its impossible for me to accurately display my table on here. ONE COLUMN LABLED MANUFACTURERS with one of the 7 names, ONE OTHER NAMED CATEGORY TYPE with one of the 8 category types. Need to give me ONE COLUMN with their corresponding ID numbers seperated by commas so a productcode with manufacturer1 that is a refrigerator would look like , [102,41]

Comment: Is the manufacturer category ID essentially a manufacturer ID?  What is a product?  Would a product under category type "oven" be "manufacturer3's oven"?  Is the gist of the problem that you get something that says "manufacturer4,oven" and you want to output "105,46" (lookup ID code based on text)?  Or you want to generate an exhaustive list of all legitimate manufacturer/product category combinations? Is the inventory list the basis?  What, exactly, does the inventory list look like (add it to the question)?  How should duplicates be handled (several models per manufacturer, same ID codes)?

Comment: George - much of the confusion may be semantics.  Could I take a stab at rewording the question in a more generic way?  If it ends up not being exactly what you're trying to answer, you could roll it back or edit the edit.

Comment: George, has the problem been resolved?

Comment: Yessir, everything is good on my end thank you for you time everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

George, if I understand correctly, you'd like the output to be the codes separated by commas...

Have you tried using VLOOKUP to look up the individual codes based on the text (eg manufacturer name) and then concatenating the looks ups with " ," if you need to have everything in the same cell?

I visualize something like...

=VLOOKUP(manufacturerTextCell, lookupTable, 2,0)&" ,"&VLOOKUP(productTypeText, lookupTable, 2,0)

Comment: You beat me to it.  I thought that might be all he was looking for but the description looked like it might be more complicated than that.  I was writing up virtually the same answer to bounce it off him when your answer showed up.

Comment: Yeah, I thought there might be a more all inclusive solution I figured I could possible do it that way. Just didn't know whether or not excel had some way to write 2 values into 1 cell seperated by commas.

Comment: George, I'm not sure if you saw this **&" ,"&** between the vlookups? It'll connect the looked up values with a comma in the same cell. Does this address your concern?

Comment: Yessir, everything is good on my end thank you for you time everyone.